# mongos is not listen when configured for sharded architecture (version 3.4)

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Deal all,
I am trying to mount a sharded mongodb server. I configured a replica set, and a configure replicat set. Both replicate are composd from 3 servers

```
root     23792     1  0 14:43 ?        00:01:55 mongod --replSet rs01 --journal --port 27102 --shardsvr --dbpath /mongo/rs01i01/ --logpath /mongo/rs01i01/mongo_102.log --fork
root     23820     1  0 14:44 ?        00:01:56 mongod --replSet rs01 --journal --port 27103 --shardsvr --dbpath /mongo/rs01i02/ --logpath /mongo/rs01i02/mongo_103.log --fork
root     23852     1  0 14:45 ?        00:01:21 mongod --replSet rs01 --journal --port 27101 --shardsvr --dbpath /mongo/rs01iar/ --logpath /mongo/rs01iar/mongo_101.log --fork
root     25240     1  0 16:18 ?        00:01:37 mongod --replSet conf --journal --port 27201 --dbpath /mongo/config --logpath /mongo/config/mongo_201.log --fork
root     25269     1  0 16:19 ?        00:01:37 mongod --replSet conf --journal --port 27202 --dbpath /mongo/config2 --logpath /mongo/config2/mongo_202.log --fork
root     25297     1  0 16:19 ?        00:01:38 mongod --replSet conf --journal --port 27203 --dbpath /mongo/config3 --logpath /mongo/config3/mongo_203.log --fork
```

However, when I try in the last step, to start mongo, the process is lunched  (3 times :O ) but is not listening on the corresponding port.

```
mongos --port 27301 --configdb conf/127.0.0.1:27201,127.0.0.1:27202,127.0.0.1:27203 --logpath /mongo/mongos/mongos_27301.log --fork
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 9803
```

but, mongo does not connect on that port

```
mongo --port 27301
MongoDB shell version v3.4.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27301/
2017-11-01T22:56:00.898+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27301, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2017-11-01T22:56:00.899+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27301, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Your config servers mongod should have `--configsvr` parameter